# Piecewise plot does not show all components

Tags: plotting

I have a function `SA[zs,zh]` where I want to do a `ParametricPlot` of a `Piecewise` function with the x-axis being `tzs[zs,zh]`. I have tried using `ConditionalExpression`, it produces the plot but there is a "gap" between the two piecewise components. I also tried to use `Piecewise` directly but it won't plot the second component (a constant) of the piecewise.

I want to know,

1. Why there is a "gap" between the two piecewise components when using `ConditionalExpression` and how to resolve it?
2. Why the second component of the piecewise function won't plot when using `Piecewise`?

I have checked my code and there seem to be no problem at all.

```
d = 3;
ag = 10;
pg = 10;
wp = 20;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
tzsint[z_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := z^d/Sqrt[f[z, zh] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d))]
tzs[zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zsr, zhr}, {zsr, zhr} = Rationalize[{zs, zh}, 0]; NIntegrate[tzsint[z, zsr, zhr], {z, 0, zsr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 100]]
SAint[z_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := (zs^d/(z^d Sqrt[f[z, zh] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d))]))
SAintreg[z_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ] := (zs^d/(z^d Sqrt[(zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d))]))
SA[zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{zsr, zhr}, {zsr, zhr} = Rationalize[{zs, zh}, 0]; NIntegrate[SAint[z, zsr, zhr] - SAintreg[z, zsr], {z, 0, zsr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 100]]

ParametricPlot[{ConditionalExpression[{tzs[zs, 0.1355], SA[zs, 0.1355]}, zs <= 0.1354688], ConditionalExpression[{tzs[zs, 0.1355], SA[0.1354688, 0.1355]}, zs >= 0.1354688]}, {zs, 0, 0.9999943 0.1355}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Blue, Thick}}, PlotRange -> Full, AspectRatio -> 3/4, ImageSize -> Large]

ParametricPlot[{tzs[zs, 0.1355], Piecewise[{{SA[zs, 0.1355], zs < 0.1354688}, {SA[0.1354688, 0.1355], 0.1354688 < zs}}]}, {zs, 0, 0.9999943 0.1355}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Blue, Thick}}, PlotRange -> Full, AspectRatio -> 3/4, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Using `ConditionalExpression`,

[image: Image1]

Using `Piecewise`,

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

d = 3;
ag = 10;
pg = 10;
wp = 20;

SetOptions[NIntegrate,
  AccuracyGoal -> ag,
  PrecisionGoal -> pg,
  WorkingPrecision -> wp,
  MaxRecursion -> 100];

f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
tzsint[z_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
 z^d/Sqrt[f[z, zh] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d))]
tzs[zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{zsr, zhr},
  {zsr, zhr} = Rationalize[{zs, zh}, 0];
  NIntegrate[tzsint[z, zsr, zhr], {z, 0, zsr}]]
SAint[z_, zs_, zh_] :=
  (zs^d/(z^d Sqrt[f[z, zh] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d))]));
SAintreg[z_, zs_] :=
 (zs^d/(z^d Sqrt[(zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d))]))
SA[zs_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{zsr, zhr},
  {zsr, zhr} = Rationalize[{zs, zh}, 0];
  NIntegrate[SAint[z, zsr, zhr] - SAintreg[z, zsr], {z, 0, zsr}]]
```

Using [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) requires values for [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) and [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html) that are larger than their defaults

```
ParametricPlot[{tzs[zs, 0.1355],
  Piecewise[{
    {SA[zs, 0.1355], zs < 0.1354688},
    {SA[0.1354688, 0.1355], 0.1354688 < zs}}]},
 {zs, 0, 0.9999943 0.1355},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20],
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Blue, Thick}},
 PlotRange -> Full,
 AspectRatio -> 3/4,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotPoints -> 125,
 MaxRecursion -> 10]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, but even if it can plot successfully, there is still a gap, why is it? Also, why does `Piecewise` require `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`?

Comment: To eliminate the gap increase the `PlotPoints` more (e.g., 200); however, there is a tradeoff between quality and speed. The greater `PlotPoints` and/or `MaxRecursion` the slower the plotting. You must decide what quality is acceptable given the complexity of the calculations involved. In any of the plotting functions the adaptive sampling can miss features. From the documentation for `Plot`: "Since only a finite number of sample points are used, it is possible for Plot to miss features of f. Increasing the settings for PlotPoints and MaxRecursion will often catch such features."

Comment: While you provide a solution, it is not clear why `Piecewise` behaves differently from `ConditionalExpression`.

Comment: @yarchik - With `ConditionalExpression` there are two distinct functions and the adaptive sampling is applied to each separately. With `Piecewise` there is only one function (which happens to have two distinct regions) so the adaptive sampling is only applied once.